# Memory leak in CPP module

Tags: visual-c++

I have a cpp service which is built using cxx file. How can I analyze memory leak in this file using CRT library?

Tried with adding

```
#define new new(_NORMAL_BLOCK_,__FILE__,__LINE__)
```

But its showing error.
Is that the same way?

Comment: If this is Visual Studio please add that tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#define DEBUG_NEW new(__FILE__, __LINE__) 
#define new DEBUG_NEW
```